# Обработка динамического URL

Tags: регулярные-выражения, nginx

На сайте есть урлы типа:

```
http://exemple.com/page/page1/
http://exemple.com/page/page2/
```

где вместо page1 и page2 может быть все что угодно.

Пытаюсь данные урлы обработать с помощью nginx и выполнить условие.
Делаю это следующим образом, но почему-то ничего не выходит, условие не срабатывает.

```
if ( $request_uri = "/page/(.*)/" ) {
......
}
```

Что я делаю не так?

Comment: Очень может быть, что вам не нужны все эти регулярные выражения, а задачу можно решить одним location /page/ {...}. Расскажите больше что вы конфигурите, а не про эти page1/2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

согласно [примерам в интернете](http://wiki.umisoft.ru/%D0%9F%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%80_%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BD%D1%84%D0%B8%D0%B3%D1%83%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE_%D1%84%D0%B0%D0%B9%D0%BB%D0%B0_%D0%B4%D0%BB%D1%8F_nginx), требующийся оператор сравнения может выглядеть примерно так:

```
if ( $request_uri ~ "^/page/" ) {
  ...
}
```

---

хотя (наверняка ввиду незнания подробностей стоящей перед вами задачи) у меня есть подозрение, что вам, скорее, подойдёт директива *location*:

```
location ~ /page/ {
  ...
}
```

Comment: тильда вряд ли подразумевалась

Comment: @Etki, вполне возможно, что автор отметил ответ принятым по ошибке. в любом случае, ему виднее, сработало ли моё предложение именно так, как ему надо.